# react form events are not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have a simple form in react. Same piece of code is working in net (w3 schools). But it is not working my project. Events are not fired for me. onChange event is not firing. I tried changing to functional components and other ways like binding event with this.bind..none of them worked.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = { username: '' };
}
myChangeHandler = (event) => {
 console.log('myChangeHandler');
 this.setState({username: event.target.value});
}
render() {
return (
  <form>
  <h1>Hello {this.state.username}</h1>
  <p>Enter your name:</p>
  <input
    type='text'
    onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
  />
  </form>
 );
}
}
```

below is how i render it,

```
import React from 'react';
import { MyForm } from './MyForm';

export default function ViewForm() {
  return (<div>        
    <MyForm />
  </div>);
}
```

below is my webpack.config.js,

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
 context: __dirname,
 entry: './src/index.js',
 output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  filename: 'main.js',  
  publicPath: '/',

 },
 devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    port: 8030,
    open: true
 },
 module: {
  rules: [
     {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
     },
     {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
     },
     {
        test: /\.(png|j?g|svg|gif)?$/,
        use: 'file-loader'
     }
   ]
 },
 plugins: [
  new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
     template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
     filename: 'index.html'
  })
 ]
};
```

below is how it rendered in background,

[image]

below is my .babelrc

```
{
 "presets": [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
      "browsers": [
        "last 2 Chrome versions",
        "last 2 Firefox versions",
        "last 2 Safari versions",
        "last 2 iOS versions",
        "last 1 Android version",
        "last 1 ChromeAndroid version",
        "ie 11"
      ]
    }
    }
  ],
 "@babel/preset-react"
 ],
 "plugins": [
  "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
 ]
}
```

Comment: I suspect you need to choose a babel preset to enable the fat arrow auto-binding. Do you have a `.babelrc` in your project? [This might help](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/babel/). Webpack can be a pig to configure correctly, we have all wasted many hours trying to make it do simple things.

Comment: yes i have .babelrc in my project

Comment: I am using webpack 5. If I remove htmlwebpackplugin and add webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin() from webpack configuration it's working. It might sound wierd but it's happening don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `bind` your method while using class component:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

export class MyForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: '' };
    // this line below
    this.myChangeHandler = this.myChangeHandler.bind(this);
  }
  myChangeHandler = (event) => {
    console.log('myChangeHandler');
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <h1>Hello {this.state.username}</h1>
        <p>Enter your name:</p>
        <input
          type='text'
          onChange={this.myChangeHandler}
        />
      </form>
   );
  }
}
```

See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) for an explanation of why the binding is necessary.

Comment: Even if i add that line it is not working in my sample. In w3 schools sample with out that also it is working fine. Don't know what is issue in my sample ->https://www.w3schools.com/react/showreact.asp?filename=demo2_react_forms_handling

Comment: @Mahesh Then it's about what else you have in your local environment. Purge `node_modules` and reinstall perhaps? I assume this because sounds like you can render the app, see it in the browser and there are no errors.

Comment: I don't have any errors in console. i have deleted and reinstalled node_modules. but still no luck.

Comment: Firstly you want to add the image to your post. Secondly i see no issues with everything you've posted here. The issue is somewhere else (assuming you have the binding of course).

Comment: yes i am binding as i removed arrow function. If arrow function is there we don't need binding